# How to log the current function name in Dart?

Tags: objective-c, function, logging, dart

In Objective-C I can log the current function name using `__func__` from `C99`:

```
NSLog(@"%s", __func__);
```

How can I do this in Dart?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't in general. Dart does not have such a feature.

What you can do is to take the first line of `StackTrace.current.toString()` write that in your log. The [stack_trace package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stack_trace) may help you parse the stack trace. It knows about the most common stack trace formats.